# Size of every column Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, memory

I want to get sum of every column, such as

| id_size | book*t_itle_size* | other colum sizes ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3343 | 89472837 | ... |

My variant was

```
select sum(pg_column_size(bks.*)) from books bks;
```

But It gives

| sum |
| --- |
| 3793944 |

What I want, I written at top

Comment: `select sum(pg_column_size(id)) as id_size, sum(pg_column_size(book_title)) as book_title_size, ... from books` If there's a lot of columns, write a little program or function to create the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dynamic sql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and iterate over [`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wtnwh8v7)

```sql
create or replace function column_sizes(target_table regclass) 
    returns table (column_name text, column_size bigint) 
    language plpgsql stable parallel restricted as $function$
declare 
    rec record;
    parsed_target_table text[]:=parse_ident(target_table::text);
    schema_name text:=case when parsed_target_table[2] is not null then
      parsed_target_table[1] end;
    table_name text:=parsed_target_table[array_upper(parsed_target_table,1)];
begin
    for rec in execute format(' select  column_name 
                                from    information_schema.columns 
                                where   (%1$L is null or table_schema = %1$L) 
                                and     (%2$L is null or table_name   = %2$L)',
                                schema_name,
                                table_name  ) loop
        return query execute format(
            'select %1$L,sum(pg_column_size(%1$I))::bigint from %s',
             rec.column_name,
             target_table);
    end loop;
end $function$;
```

The problem with returning it sideways like you presented is that you'd have to return a record and each time specify its columns on each call, or return into a table created dynamically under a predefined name, then read from that. Might be easier to work with or pivot/crosstab a vertical output.

---

The reason your query didn't work is that

```sql
select sum(pg_column_size(bks.*)) from t1 AS bks;
```

is evaluated to

```sql
select sum(pg_column_size( (id,book_title,other_column) )) from t1 AS bks;
```

You were effectively summing up the sizes of records constructed out of all columns of the table.